# Parsing a DSL into instance of given model

Tags: java, xtext

I am trying to implement a DSL that has to translate to a already implemented model.
The DSL will describe instances of the classes from the given model, so it is inappropriate to use a DSLGenerator, parsing the DSL to java-files. I would like to load the described instances into javaruntime. From an architectural perspective i need a DSL-Loader class that translates the DSL into instancing-statements and loads the instances into the java runtime.
It is possible to do this with the provided DSLGenerator. However it seems to be realy ugly. Are there other, in this situation more appropriate, possibilities to process the AST into a instance-model?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that.
If i understand correctly, you want to use an existing metamodel instead of a generated one to build your grammar.

Actually you have to replace the following instruction at the beginning of your grammar:

```
generate "yourMetamodelUri"
```

by

```
import "yourMetamodelUri".
```

You can get more informations in this [article](http://www.lorenzobettini.it/2014/02/switching-from-an-inferred-ecore-model-to-an-imported-one-in-your-xtext-grammar/)